# move record from one table to another inserting X times

Tags: mysql

I've got a table that resembles this:

```
id
name
datetime
quantity
```

and I'd like to, with SQL, move these records from one table to another that will not have the quantity column, inserting record X times where X is the value of quantity so ....

```
id name       datetime    quantity
----------------------------------
5  book-order 15-Mar-2010 3

# becomes

id name       datetime  
------------------------
5  book-order 15-Mar-2010
6  book-order 15-Mar-2010
7  book-order 15-Mar-2010
```

Is there a way to do this in pure SQL?

Comment: Yes, probably with a stored procedure [declaring a cursor](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html) and iterating all the rows in your original table. You'll need to do every insert in a while loop though, unless you build up a dynamic `VALUES ()` string to execute

Comment: Its not pure SQL but if you use MySQL, in the operations tab of the table you want copied, you can copy the table to a new tale and just drop the quantity column afterwards. As for pure SQL though, I'm not sure that's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it, assuming that quantity is no more than 100:

```
insert into t2(name, datetime)
    select name, datetime
    from t1 join
         (select d1*10+d2 as num
          from (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all
                select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
               ) d1 cross join
               (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all
                select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
              ) d2
         ) nums
         on nums.num < t1.qty
```

The hard part is generating a numbers table, if the quantity gets too big.

Answer (score 1):

If ID on destination table is an auto increment field, you might consider using something like this query:

```
insert into books2 (name, datetime)
select
  name, datetime
from
  books inner join
  (select 0 n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3
   union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 n union all
   select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) nums
  on books.quantity > nums.n;
```

This will select all books orders multiple times, based on books.quantity, and will insert them into table books2. This query is limited to a maximum of 10, but can be expanded.

See working fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c859/1).